# Downcasting an object doesn't change the object itself?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, casting

So I ran across some code

```
IFirst x  { get; private set; }
...
x = GetItem();

if (x == null) return;

ISecond y = x as ISecond;  // this is the line I have issue with
```

`GetItem` defined at

```
public IFirst GetItem() {
  //abridge
  return new ConcreteA();
}
```

`ConcreteA` defined as

```
class ConcreteA : IFirst, ISecond {

}
```

The part where I am confused is when I downcast an item and return it from a function it seems that item does not loose its full identity.  Meaning if I return `ConcreateA` as `IFirst` I would have expected it only to be an `IFirst` object.

But from the code in the first block it seems x, even though defined as `IFirst` explicitly can access its `ISecond` identity, and I assume its `ConcreteA` identity if need be?

Is this what is expected or am I missing a piece of code that is maintaining the conversion somewhere?

What is this behavior or pattern called in programming or C# specifically?

Comment: That seems to be the expected behaviour. On some languages (For example in C++), if you downcast a class object that is not a pointer object splicing will occurr (That seems to be what you were expecting). In C#, all instances are pointers bellow, so you will not lose any of the properties of the object.

Comment: **Casting** does not change the object at all, it just makes other parts of it accessable (unless you have an explicit cast-operator, which may lead to a loss of information).

Comment: @HimBromBeere, just to make it more clear: this applies for C# but not for C++ where object slicing might take place.

Comment: Sorry @Servy I don't agree while the title is better and the answer might indirectly answer the question -- the question in the linked duplicate is not the same.

Comment: @Mike I'm glad that the duplicate answered your question for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected and part of the object oriented paradigm and not specific to c#.

You can think of the variables as boxes. And a different objects fit in different boxes but they are always the same object. Casting changes nothing but the shape of the box.

In your case you downcast so you put ConcreteA into a more restricted box (in this analogy).